# Is there a way to generate a random list of users using Instagram API or otherwise?

Tags: random, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to train a data model and would like a random list of Instagram users that I can manually review for desired characteristics.

I wasn't able to find any random list generator in the API or online. Other ways of finding users (have a certain word in their handle, hashtag something specific, follow someone specific) seem like they would create a biased dataset.

Open to any recommendations or hacks to get a pseudorandom list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get random user list.

You can search a random hashtag posts and get the users from the response you get, it will be pretty random.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

you will get an array of post objects, with that you will get user info for the post.